# How can I stop background audio played by other apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have an app for WP7, using `BackgroundAudioPlayer` as we need to play in the background. The problem is, when there's already an app playing audio in the background, I can't get my `AudioPlaybackAgent` work, the previous music just keep playing.

The document introduced this way,

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Close();
```

by which I can only close the audio that is played by myself or Zune, but it doesn't work when the audio is played by other apps.

So is there a way to close all the playing audio?

Comment: Even it were possible (which I doubt) I would recommend NOT doing it... as a user I would remove your app from my phone since what you describe is really annoying for an app to do!

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe clearly, it's a music app, no one wants to have two music playing at the same time. That's why Zune itself does the same thing.

Comment: I would think it should happen automatically when you start playing yours. I think I have seen some documentation mentioning that when you start playback using MediaElement - the currently playing background audio should start automatically.

Comment: Thanks @xyzzer, the problem is indeed about the start. The `Play()` method does work, but should have been called earlier. There I wrote an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I fixed it.

What I did to get it play is like this, first I set a track to the player:

```
BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = ...;
```

Then an `OnPlayStateChanged` event will fire in the background agent, where I call the `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play()` method. This seems to work great.

But if the background player is already being used by another app, the `PlayState` won't change to `TrackReady` when I set the track, and consequently the event won't fire.

To fix this, I simply call the `.Play()` method in the main UI thread, right after setting the track. And it works.